# how do I sort list in python

Tags: python, sorting

I input like this -> 10 79 8 51 2

and I want to get `[2, 8, 10, 51, 79]`

but I get `[10, 2, 51, 79, 8]`

please tell me what's wrong with my code?

**python**

```
list = input().split()
print(list)
for i in range(0, 4):
    print(i)
    for j in range(i+1, 5):
        if list[i] > list[j]:
            print(list[i],list[j])
            list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i]
            print(list)
        else:
            print(j, list[i], list[j])
            print("don't switch")
```

Comment: Have you tried using print statements to debug your code? Maybe an IDE debugger? Those tools might allow you to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: @KevinSheng From the OP's posted code, it seems like he has tried using print statements to debug his code.

Comment: FYI it's a bad idea to shadow built-in names like `list`. Use a non-reserved word for variable names instead.

Comment: You have a list of strings, not integers. `10 > 2`, but `"10" < "2"`.

Comment: Note that you *don't* get `[10, 2, 51, 79, 8]`, but `['10', '2', '51', '79', '8']`. The quotes are significant.

Comment: Also, for all the answerers, please don't answer with `sorted(list)`. It is clear from the question that the OP is trying to program a bubble sort without using built-in Python functions.

Comment: @kdj001106 Please consider accepting an answer; this tells others that your issue is resolved and helps them find the correct answer more easily.

Answer (score 6):

The logic of your sort is correct, however it's not working on what you think it is. In practice, it is working on a list of *strings* (not *integers*), and so the comparison is lexicographic, not numeric. Under this criteria, your list is sorted.

If you would change your input to `list = [10, 79, 8, 51, 2]`, you'd get the result you want. (Asides from that, it's better not to use names like `list`.)

Answer (score 3):

There are three problems with your code.

1. Instead of iterating from 0 to 4, or i+1 to 5, do this:

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(list)):
```

2. As Ami Tavory pointed out, you are iterating over STRINGS of numbers, not the numbers themselves. To fix this, change every reference to `list[i]` to `int(list[i])`. Or before the for loops, you can do this:

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    list[i] = int(list[i])
```

Or, even more succinctly, as Stef mentioned:

```
list = [int(x) for x in list]
```

This converts every item in `list` to an integer instead of a string.

3. As Random Davis mentioned, don't name your variables after existing types in Python. Name `list` something like `lst` instead.

Comment: It's much worse than just a bad idea to name a list `list`. You can list it as a third big problem of this code. As for problem 2), it is the perfect opportunity to introduce list comprehensions: `lst = [int(x) for x in lst]`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way to write your code . check this out :

```
a = list(map(int,input().split()[:5])) ## Enter 5 numbers with in one line with one space distance
#This method can also be used for N  numbers , you just need to change 4.

tol = len(a) 
for j in range(tol-1):       ## Helps to check sorting process again and again until all of numbers are sorted
    for i in range(tol-1):  ## To compare each number with next one
        if a[i] > a[i+1]:
            temp = a [i]
            a [i] = a[i+1]
            a [i+1]=temp
        else:
            continue
print(a)
```

input :**10 79 8 51 2** and Output: **[2, 8, 10, 51, 79]**

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to sort list is:

```
list1 = [10, 79, 8, 51, 2]
print(sorted(list1))

output:[2, 8, 10, 51, 79]
```

Comment: This is the simplest way, but in the OP's example they are using typed input which is represented as strings in Python.

Answer (score -2):

I dont know if that will work but i think that sort less. Try maybe to increase your number of loop.
Or try this :

```
list = input().split()

#Turn every value of your list into int and not string
for i in range(0, len(list)): 
    list[i] = int(list[i]) 

print(list)
  
# Sorting the list
list.sort() 
  
print(list)
```